# Rearrange keys in std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a map looking like this:

0, 1234

1, 5678

2, 9012

Now, for example I remove the entry with key 1, so the map looks like this:

0, 1234

2, 9012

Now I want to rearrange the keys, so that the map looks like this:

0, 1234

1, 9012

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why then not use a vector? you don't need the index, vector.begin() is your 0 index.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you ask for is not possible directly, hence it would help if you explain why you think you need it. keys in maps are `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    std::vector<int> v = {100, 200, 300};
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&j](auto const& p) {
        std::cout << "index = " << j++ << " value = " << p << std::endl;
        });

    /* Delete item at index = 1 */

    v.erase(v.begin() + 1);
    j = 0;
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&j](auto const& p) {
        std::cout << "index = " << j++ << " value = " << p << std::endl;
        });
}
```

**Output**

```
index = 0 value = 100
index = 1 value = 200
index = 2 value = 300
index = 0 value = 100
index = 1 value = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want sound very unlogical. The key is unique and is used to lookup values (very fast). Now you want to change the key, this is weird. You likely need a flat type of list type.

You should look into `std::list` or `std::vector`. The index is automatically 'updated' when you remove items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only by erasing the previous element and re-insert it with a new key